# Uploading files without causing server side errors during the process

Tags: php, upload

I continually make tweaks to my software and upload it to the server. As I have customers using my online software all the time, if a PHP file is partially uploaded (let's say it takes 3 seconds to upload) when a customer clicks a link (say at the 1 second mark) they get an error because the file is still uploading...

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /inc/functions.php on line 475
```

As I'm in Australia, our internet... well... "isn't very fast" is a nice way of putting it.

Are there any techniques used when uploading files so it does not cause errors for customers using the software?

Only thing I can thing of is uploading files to say another directory then running a PHP script that copies the files across super fast... But is there better solutions?

**FINAL CODE**

Thanks to Greg below I was able to figure out the best way to do things. Thought I'd share my final code. It's a bit rough but does the trick... Hopefully it helps someone

```
<?php

// root path
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

// messages
$GLOBALS['copied'] = array();
$GLOBALS['failed'] = array();
$GLOBALS['folders'] = array();

// you have to submit the form (added security)
if (isset($_POST['copy'])) {

    $GLOBALS['devuploads_folder'] = '_devuploads';

    function find_files($dir) {
        if ($dh = opendir(ABSPATH . $dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

                // ignore files
                if ($file === '.' || $file === '..')
                    continue;

                // delete temporary files (optional)
                if ($file == '.DS_Store') {
                    unlink(ABSPATH . $dir . $file);
                    continue;
                }

                // determine paths                  
                $live_path = str_replace($GLOBALS['devuploads_folder'] . '/', '', $dir . $file);                
                $dev_file = $dir . $file;                   
                $live_file = $live_path;
                $dev_file_path = ABSPATH . $dir . $file;                    
                $live_file_path = ABSPATH . $live_path;

                // it's a file
                if (is_file(ABSPATH . $dir . $file)) {  

                    // check if the file has been updated or it's a brand newy
                    $updated_file = $new_file = false;
                    if (file_exists($live_file_path)) {                                 
                        $dev_file_modified = filemtime($dev_file_path);     
                        $live_file_modified = filemtime($live_file_path);                                               
                        if ($dev_file_modified > $live_file_modified)
                            $updated_file = true;                       
                    } else {
                        $new_file = true;
                    }

                    // move the file
                    if ($updated_file || $new_file) {
                        if (copy($dev_file_path, $dev_file_path . '.bak')) {
                            if (rename($dev_file_path . '.bak', $live_file_path))
                                if ($new_file)
                                    $GLOBALS['copied'][] = '<strong>New File:</strong> ' . $dev_file . ' moved to ' . $live_file;   
                                else
                                    $GLOBALS['copied'][] = $dev_file . ' moved to ' . $live_file;   
                            else
                                $GLOBALS['failed'][] = '<strong>Rename failed:</strong> ' . $dev_file . ' to ' . $live_file;
                        } else {
                            $GLOBALS['failed'][] = '<strong>Copy failed:</strong> ' . $dev_file . ' to ' . $dev_file . '.bak';
                        }
                    }

                // it's a folder
                } else if (is_dir(ABSPATH . $dir . $file)) {

                    // create new folder if it doesn't exist
                    if (!is_dir($live_file_path)) {
                        $GLOBALS['folders'][] = '<strong>Created:</strong> ' . $live_file;  
                        mkdir($live_file_path, 0755);   
                    }

                    // keep digging
                    find_files($dir . $file . '/');

                }

            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }

    find_files($GLOBALS['devuploads_folder'] . '/');

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Copy Changes</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    h1 {
        font: normal 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 24px;
        }
    p, li {
        font: normal 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>

<?php   
if (!empty($GLOBALS['failed'])) {
    echo '<h1>Errors</h1>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($GLOBALS['failed'] AS $message) {
        echo '<li>' . $message . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

if (!empty($GLOBALS['folders'])) {
    echo '<h1>New Folders</h1>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($GLOBALS['folders'] AS $message) {
        echo '<li>' . $message . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

if (!empty($GLOBALS['copied'])) {
    echo '<h1>Copied</h1>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($GLOBALS['copied'] AS $message) {
        echo '<li>' . $message . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

if (empty($GLOBALS['failed']) && empty($GLOBALS['folders']) && empty($GLOBALS['copied']))
    echo '<p>No updates made.</p>';
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="copy" value="1" />
<p><input type="submit" value="Copy Files" /></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this error is usually caused by unfinished function. Check if you have incomplete pair of `{` and `}`

Comment: @silent the reason it has an unfinished function is because the file is partially uploaded as I specified in my question... There's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: ok, I miss understood the question. I though, by upload is the user uploading files. Not source code.

Comment: YOu should at least add some POST var that takes a password that's long or something…`POST` by itself is bad security

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your server is Linux (or other Unix variant), then the `mv` command is *atomic* and can do this sort of instantaneous update. First copy the file to a temporary name (like `file.php.new`), and then log in to the server and

```
mv file.php.new file.php
```

(this works even if `file.php` exists, it will be replaced by the new one).

Comment: Thanks @Greg! So if I were to update say 100 files, what would be the best way without renaming each file before upload and running the `mv` command for each file? Would my idea of uploading all files into a folder and use PHP to move them be the best option?

Comment: You could write a script to do that. However, be sure to *move* them instead of *copying* them, that's the key point. You can use [`rename()`](http://php.net/rename) to do that.

Comment: Interesting why you said to _move_ instead of _copy_. Is there a reason for that? The reason I ask is the FTP software I use I can set to only upload files that have changed rather than uploading every file which takes a few minutes each time. It would be great to leave a duplicate on the server so the upload time is only a few seconds. Does _copying_ the files cause issues somewhere?

Comment: Yes, copying is the root of the problem. When you copy a file, it takes time to move the bytes from the source to the destination. You observed this in the scenario you described in your question (the copying was done over the network link, so it was easy to notice). The same sort of thing happens when you copy a file locally, although your CPU and hard drive is much faster than your network. It is possible for a client to get a partial file when you copy. However, moving/renaming a file moves a *complete* source file on top of the destination file, leaving no partial file gap.

Comment: The ftp program should be able to take care of this, at least it is what always happens (unless I specify otherwise) when I use the ftp option in NetBeans. Of course that could still lead to problems if multiple files have changed and some depend on others...

Comment: That's great Greg, appreciate you taking the time to explain. I'll do some tests and see how it goes. Like you mentioned copying a file on the local machine will be much faster than over the network. I'd just really love to not have to upload all the files each time I make a small change :) I'll keep an eye on the error_logs to ensure it's not causing issues. When my software grows even more and error_logs start to appear from uploads, I will have to reconsider your advice :)

Comment: @jeroen I use FileZilla... Looks like it must overwrite the file on the fly rather than uploading a temp version and overwriting it server side once it's done. Hmmm... something to consider. I'm a bit picky with my FTP programs...

Comment: Came up with a good idea to overcome the copying issue. What I can do is make a `copy` of the files that changed in the temporary upload folder and then `rename` that copy to move it to the live site. Case solved :)