# Netbeans 7.2 FTP is incredibly slow

Tags: performance, netbeans, ftp, netbeans-7.2

I just created a new project that connects to a remote website to edit the files. It's been 10 minutes and it still hasn't finished downloading.

The site is no bigger than 30mb and I have a decent internet connection.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Very sad, it happens with me too...

Answer (score 1):

Verify what NetBeans is doing exactly (in IDE log, in the Output window). Also try to switch Passive/Active mode on/off.

Comment: in my log when I upload Netbeans is NOOPing mostly, then after a minute of freezing all happens rapidly, in desired time. On FreeBSD 9.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for me too.

I've just uploaded a project with Netbeans and it took 4:47 minutes. I've done the same with FileZilla and it took 1:48 minutes.

I think it's because it dones many other operations. For example, uploading the same file:

Netbeans:

```
  ...
RNFR forms.php
RNTO forms.php.old
Rename successful.
RNFR forms.php.new
RNTO forms.php
Rename successful.
DELE formus.php.old
File delete OK.
  ...
```

Filezilla:

```
  ...
Command: put "P:\Projects\...\forms.php" "forms.php"
State:   Successfully transfered, transfered 4.096 bytes in 1 seconds
  ...
```

They should let us configuring this behavior.

Comment: It may be slower but is advantageous and I wish FileZilla had an option to turn this behaviour on because if a client is requesting the page you are uploading at the time then they will most likely receive an error about an unexpected end of file. As far as I can see, the way netbeans is handling this will prevent it. I could be wrong, but see here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843454/uploading-files-without-causing-server-side-errors-during-the-process[/link] and also [link]http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/4004[/link]